# Workflow - Set Account Name

Tags: workflow, required-field

I created a workflow rule to update Account Names. I want that all my Account Names automatically fill as for example : Contact.FullName+' '+Contact.Phone.
The workflow rule work but the field Account name still mandatory when I create a new Account .
Since the Account Name is set in the in the workflow rule, is it possible make this field not mandatory?

Comment: What happens if you have more than one contact in an account?

Answer (score 1):

No It is not possible to remove account name field from mandatory that is standard salesforce field of standard object.

The work around would be enter some dummy value while creating account and your workflow rule will update the name with correct name or override the new and edit account page with custom form to create account. In the custom form you can have your own set of field and your customized control on all the fields